# Passing header parameters while loading Video in VideoJs

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, video.js, request-headers

I am trying to load a video into VideoJS player in a react project. The Video is returned from a web service taking specific token that authenticate the user.

Let's say the video is returned from the below API call:

> localhost:8080/video/1/

In order to play this video, the user should be authenticated. In other words, the API takes the below header to return a successful result:

> auth: token

My VideoJs player is built in a React component as below:

```js
import React from 'react'
import videojs from 'video.js'

export default class VideoComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
      this.videoJsOptions = {
        sources: [{
           src: 'http://localhost:8080/video/1/',
          type: 'video/mp4',
        }],
      }
      let player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.videoJsOptions, function onPlayerReady() {
        console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
      })

      this.player = player
  }
  render () {
      return (
            <div data-vjs-player>
              <video ref={node => this.videoNode = node} className="video-js"></video>
            </div>
      )       
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How is it possible to let my video component take the token of the calling URL and pass it the request header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put this component as a child of another component whose sole responsibility is to make the API call and render the `VideoComponent` if the user is authorized. Something along these lines.

You'll probably want some type of redirect or error message feedback to the user if they are not authorized. I did not incorporate that in my code snippet.

```js
export default class VideoAuth extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isAuthorized: false
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const authRequest = await someAuthRequest()
        if (authRequest.ok) {// or however the data structure looks like
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.isAuthenticated ? <VideoComponent /> : <div> Authorizing... </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this solve my issue? I need to pass the token in the header of the api retrieving the video. In other words,  http://localhost:8080/video/1/ requires a token in the request header. Otherwise the video is not being loaded in the player because the request is returning 401 unauthorized

Comment: @HodaBaydoun Where does this token live in your application?

Comment: Yes, I have it in the localStorage, however it's not being added to the request header

Comment: Then I'm confused. I'm saying to pass whatever credentials you need into this line `const authRequest = await someAuthRequest()`. If it a successful call, then you mount the component with the video player. There's a ternary to stop `VideoComponent` from prematurely mounting before your request finishes. What other information does your video player need in order to play? If it need info from the request, then do the same thing, except wrap the ternary around the `<video>` instead of making a new component